# Preventing Windows Control Keys in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm looking at replicating a game in HTML5 and as part of it I want to prevent accidental presses of the Windows Control Key.

It doesn't seem to be disabled by preventDefaults();

Is there a way to suppress the key message outside of the app?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, think about all the things you could do in Javascript to someones computer if it were possible.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll leave the question open just in case but I do appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it is possible at all.  There are some libraries and scripts that attempt to accomplish at least part of this, and they should work for other keys.  Whether they work for the Windows key or not I can't tell you:

- http://binarykitten.me.uk/keyzDemo/
- http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/wiki/about
- http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/disable-ctrl-n-and-other-ctrl-key-combinations-in-javascript.html
- http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/disable-form-submit-on-enter-keypress.html#8 (see the comments for the script)
- http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-959947.html

#### Workarounds

- Place the keys you intend the user to use in your game elsewhere.  E.g. `JKLI` for movement and `AS` for actions.
- Show them a picture of a screwdriver, and tell them to remove their Windows key
- Google seems to be [introducing gamepad support to the Chrome browser](http://www.neowin.net/news/googles-chrome-browser-to-add-gamepad-support)